# Error opening PDF file generated by asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, pdf, adobe

I'm trying to generate a PDF for my website. Currently, I'm attempting to get the data from the database and display it out on my PDF file, however my main priority was actually to get the value from the asp:label and export it into pdf format. Unfortunately, when i open the PDF file generated, i got this error.

Error : There was  an error opening this document. This file is already open or in use by another application

```
protected void btnPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var doc1 = new Document();
        var filename = DDLCase.SelectedItem.Text + ".pdf";
        var output = new FileStream(Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\apr12mpsip\\Desktop", filename), FileMode.Create);
        doc1.Open();

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Header spanning 3 columns"));
        cell.Colspan = 3;
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; 
        table.AddCell(cell);
        table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 1");
        table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 1");

        doc1.Add(table);

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security = SSPI");

        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select typeofcrime, citizenreport from MemberReport where memberreportid='"+DDLCase.SelectedValue+"'", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            table.AddCell(dr[0].ToString());
            table.AddCell(dr[1].ToString());
        }
        dr.Close();


        doc1.Close();

    }
```

I checked my codes and i couldn't find any ways to solve the error and get the value successfully.

Comment: try doc1.Dispose(); after closing it.

Comment: The method doesn't help.

Comment: did you dispose output object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do

```
var doc1 = new Document();
var filename = DDLCase.SelectedItem.Text + ".pdf";
var output = new FileStream(Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\apr12mpsip\\Desktop", filename), FileMode.Create);
doc1.Open();
[... fetching some data and adding that to`doc1 ...]
doc1.Close();
```

It leaps to the eye that you do not in any way associate the `output` with the `Document doc1.` Thus, your file is not written to at all but neither is it ever closed.

Most likely you additionally want to instantiate a `PdfWriter` which writes to `output` and receives from `doc1:`

```
var doc1 = new Document();
var filename = DDLCase.SelectedItem.Text + ".pdf";
var output = new FileStream(Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\apr12mpsip\\Desktop", filename), FileMode.Create);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, output); // instantiate a PdfWriter for doc1 and output
doc1.Open();
[... fetching some data and adding that to`doc1 ...]
doc1.Close();
```

Comment: I'm able to display out my Header spanning 3 columns. But how do i display out the value from the database ?

Comment: That is a different question altogether. Please make it a stackoverflow question in its own right and provide the required information, especially what you want to achieve (how do you want your data to be displayed), what you have tried (your current code for that task) and in what way the current output does not fulfill your requirements.